# Rails 3 - Unable to create a new post while at the SHOW view of another Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-action

I have a model named "Post". I want to use a modal form to create a new post while at the SHOW view of another post. Meaning while I am viewing the post named "John" in its show view, I would like to be able to create a new post from right there.

The problem I have is that the ID of the new post remains the same as the post I am viewing, and causes the update action to be fired instead of the create action. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a new post with `Post.new` and use that in a `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for Post.new %>
  <%= render "form" %>
<% end %>
```

Of course this means you'll need to remove the `form_for` from your form partial if you have it in there, but that's a small sacrifice to make.

However if you really don't want to do that then you will have to pass through a local variable to the form partial to indicate which post you want to display. On the `show` page you'd have this:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :post => Post.new } %>
```

In the `new` and `edit` views you'd do this:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :post => @post } %>
```

The line is a little bit longer, but that would allow you to keep the `form_for` tag inside the form partial and not clog up the three other views with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. However I did not understand this entirely. I tried this and (though no errors were thrown) the Post was not created. Also, I am using a Modal-Form and not aiming to redirect to _form partial to create a new Post. Could you please guide me. Thanks again!

Comment: Correction: It was unsuccessful due to my own mistake wherein I was redirecting this to the Index (based on the current submit action's name). Bottom line, question answered! Thanks Ryan.